# EnTT - std::find_if like funtion for entity in registry

Tags: c++, entt

I want to find an entity with a specific tag. Is there a `std::find_if` like function for me to do that?

An example of what it might look like.

```cpp
struct TagComponent{
    std::string Tag;
};

entt::entity FindByTag(std::string tag){
    
    entt::entity e = m_Registry.find_if([&](auto entity){
        if(/*check if entity's tag equals to tag*/)
            return true;
        return false;
    });
}
```

Comment: `std::find` and `std::find_if` do [exist](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find). What exactly is your question? Of what type is `m_Registry`?

Comment: the `m_Registry` is of type `entt::registry`. That was just an example of what I wanted.

Comment: If it were a STL container, you could use `std::find_if` almost like you did in your example code. Since it is not, you could make it a STL container or loop through your entities and check manually or implement the requirements by `std::find_if` to use it with your `entt::registry` type, namely [LegacyInputIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator) or [LegacyForwardIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator).

Comment: try making it into an answer and you might just be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late but something like this should work:

---

Edit: @Vivick answer brought to my attention the error in my code since 0 can be a valid entity, so it should return entt::null if
found none.

```
entt::entity FindByTag(std::string tag){
    auto view = m_Registry.view<TagComponent>();
    for (auto entity : view)
    {
        auto& myTag = view.get<TagComponent>(entity);
        if (myTag.Tag == tag)
            return entity;
    }
    return entt::null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EnTT views provide iterators, which means you can use the STL with it:

```
entt::entity FindByTag(std::string tag){
    auto view = m_Registry.view<TagComponent>();
    auto end = std::cend(view);
    auto it = std::find_if(std::cbegin(view), end, [&](const auto& entity){
        const auto& myTag = view.get<TagComponent>(entity);
        return myTag.Tag == tag;
    });

    // edit to suit your needs, compare with cend, return an optional?, return entt::null?
    // return *it;

    return it == end ? entt::null : *it;
}
```